# Magento 2 : Set Dynamic User Define Time for Run cronjob?

Tags: configuration, system.xml, crontab, magento-cron

We are developing one Extension in which we provide the facility to the user to set his custom time for run corn job.

for this functionality, we provide fields in-store configuration like:

> Custom Schedule: {*/5 * * * *}

Or

> Frequency: {Monthly/Weekly/Daily}
>
> Start On: {00:00:59}(time to start)

and set this dynamic value into crontab => config -> group -> job -> **shedule**

How can we set this functionality in our Extension?

Which is the Better way for implementing this functionality?

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cron/custom-cron-ref.html

Answer (score 0):

Existing cronjobs can be overridden by setting a new schedule in the `core_config_data` table.

Let's say your user wants to update the schedule for the `catalogrule_apply_all` job (defaults to: `0 1 * * *`) to `0 5 * * *`. You'll need to do something like this:

```php
public function __construct(
   \Magento\Framework\App\Config\Storage\WriterInterface $configWriter
) {
    $this->_configWriter = $configWriter;
}

public function doStuff() {
    $scopeId = 0; // Change this to the scope of your user.
    $path = 'crontab/default/jobs/catalogrule_apply_all/schedule/cron_expr';
    $value = '0 5 * * *';

    $this->_configWriter->save($path, $value, ScopeConfigInterface::SCOPE_TYPE_DEFAULT, $scopeId);
}
```

Using raw SQL, that would look like:

```
INSERT INTO `core_config_data` (`config_id`, `scope`, `scope_id`, `path`, `value`, `updated_at`) VALUES (NULL, 'default', '0', 'crontab/default/jobs/catalogrule_apply_all/schedule/cron_expr', '0 5 * * *', CURRENT_TIME());
```

Clear the cache for the config to be updated:

```
bin/magento c:c
```

You can check that the job schedule has been taken into account by using [n98-magerun2](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun2) :

`n98-magerun2 sys:cron:list | grep catalogrule_apply_all`

Output:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------+---------------+------+------+---+---+----+
| Job                                                 | Group         | m    | h    | D | M | WD |
+-----------------------------------------------------+---------------+------+------+---+---+----+
| catalogrule_apply_all                               | default       | 0    | 5    | * | * | *  |
+-----------------------------------------------------+---------------+------+------+---+---+----+
```